# How to check if a URL exists or returns 404 using Groovy Script?

Tags: groovy

I need to check if a URL exists or returns 404 using Groovy Script. Is there any groovy api available for the same ? The corresponding java methods doesn't work with Groovy.

Answer (score 6):

You can just do:

```
def code = new URL('http://www.google.com/made.up').openConnection().with {
    requestMethod = 'HEAD'
    connect()
    responseCode
}

assert code == 404
```

Of course, if the domain doesn't exist, an Exception will be thrown

Comment: I am getting the folllowing error for the above code.
JBO-25152: Calling the constructor for class java.net.URL is not permitted.

Comment: so is this in Jenkins, or some kind of container?